# How to stop the scanner after certain lines

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I was doing a program that requires the scanner to read a certain number of lines, however, it would not stop after that number is reached. Here's the code dealing with this part:

```
for(int i=0;i<normal;i++)
     {
         int x=0;
         int y=0;
         String ans=in.nextLine();
         int[] arraya=createaarray(ans);
         x=arraya[0];
         y=arraya[1];
         matrix[x][y]=true;
     }
```

Normal-1 is the number of lines it needs to read, and createaarray is a method where it takes two numbers with a space in between them, and put them in an array. So x would be the first number, and y is the second.However, the scanner would not close after reading "normal" number of lines, and anymore input would cause an numberformatexception. Example input and error:

```
0 1
0 2
2 3
4 3
6 1
1 5
7 3

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input   string: ""
at     java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at treez.createaarray(treez.java:83)
at treez.run(treez.java:45)
at treez.<init>(treez.java:8)
at treez.main(treez.java:90)
```

I understand this is caused by an empty input, however, I have no idea how to fix it. Some help would be appreciated

Comment: Check `ans` for empty, e.g. `ans.isEmpty()`??

Comment: show the whole code.

Comment: You can use [StringUtils#isNumeric](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric-java.lang.CharSequence-) from Apache library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "normal - 1" is number of lines to read, then you should iterate the loop "normal - 1" times. In your code, I see that you start with 0 and end with "normal". The array is iterated exactly "normal" times. It should be done like that:

```
for(int i=0 ; i < normal - 1; i++) {
     int x = 0;
     int y = 0;
     String ans = in.nextLine();
     int[] arraya = createaarray(ans);
     x = arraya[0];
     y = arraya[1];
     matrix[x][y] = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `createaarray` methods returns `empty` or `null` array if input is not valid, you need to add an `if` condition before executing rest of the code, to make sure you have got a valid `array`, e.g.:

```
if(null != arraya && arraya.length > 1){
    x=arraya[0];
    y=arraya[1];
    matrix[x][y]=true;
}
```

Also, once it's done, you can close the `scanner` by calling `close()` method.